# How to send erlang functions source to riak mapreduce via HTTP?

Tags: riak

I'm trying to use Riak's mapreduce via http. his is what i'm sending:

```
{
"inputs":{
    "bucket":"test",
    "key_filters":[["matches", ".*"]]
},
"query":[
    {
        "map":{
            "language":"erlang",
            "source":"value(RiakObject, _KeyData, _Arg) -> Key = riak_object:key(RiakObject), Count = riak_kv_crdt:value(RiakObject, <<\"riak_kv_pncounter\">>), [ {Key, Count} ]."
        }
    }
]}
```

Riak fails with "[worker_startup_failed]", which isn't very informative. Could anyone please help me get this to actually execute the function?

Answer (score 1):

---

#### WARNING

Allowing arbitrary Erlang functions via map-reduce is a security risk.  Any valid Erlang can be executed, including sending your entire data set offsite or formatting the hard drive.

You have been warned.

---

However, if you implicitly trust any client that may connect to your cluster, you can allow Erlang source to be passed in a map-reduce request by setting `{allow_strfun, true}` in the riak_kv section of app.config, (or in the advanced.config if you are using riak.conf).

Once you have allowed passing an Erlang function in a map-reduce phase, you need to pass in a function of the form `fun(RiakObject,KeyData,Arg) -> [result] end.` Note that this must be an anonymous fun, so `fun` is a keyword, not a name, and it must end with end.
Your function should handle the case where `{error,notfound}` is passed as the first argument instead of an object.  Simply adding a catch-all clause to the function could accomplish that.
Perhaps something like:

```
{
"inputs":{
    "bucket":"test",
    "key_filters":[["matches", ".*"]]
},
"query":[
    {
        "map":{
            "language":"erlang",
            "source":"fun(RiakObject, _KeyData, _Arg) -> 
                           Key = riak_object:key(RiakObject), 
                           Count = riak_kv_crdt:value(
                                            RiakObject, 
                                            <<\"riak_kv_pncounter\">>), 
                           [ {Key, Count} ];
                       (_,_,_) -> [{error,0}]
                       end."
        }
    }
]}
```

Allowing the source to be passed in the request is very useful while developing and debugging. For production, you really should put the functions in a dedicated pre-compiled module that you copy to the code path of each node so that the phase spec can specify the module and function by name instead of providing arbitrary code.

```
{"map":{
   "language":"erlang",
   "module":"yourprecompiledmodule",
   "function":"functionname"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `allow_strfun` on all nodes in your cluster. To do so in Riak 2, you will need to use the `advanced.config` file to add this to the `riak_kv` configuration:

```
[
    {riak_kv, [
        {allow_strfun, true}
    ]}
].
```

The other option is to create your own Erlang module by using the compiler shipped with Riak and placing the `*.beam` file in a well-known location for Riak to find. The [`basho-patches`](http://docs.basho.com/riakee/latest/cookbooks/Rolling-Upgrade-to-Enterprise/#Basho-Patches) directory is one such place.

Please see the documentation as well:

- [`advanced.config`](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/configs/configuration-files/#Advanced-Configuration)
- [Installing custom Erlang code](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/install-custom-code/)
- [HTTP MapReduce](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/references/http/mapreduce/)
- [Using MapReduce](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/mapreduce/)
- [Advanced MapReduce](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/mapreduce/)
- [MapReduce / `curl` example](https://gist.github.com/hectcastro/6372626)